# Minimum volume is too high with headphones

Tags: volume-control, htc-sensation-xe

Got the HTC Sensation XE recently. Liking the phone and the beats headphones/ear-in phones that come with the phone.

However, the minimum volume is just too LOUD!!!

The beats integration was one of the reasons I bought the phone so I don't want to buy different headphone with volume control.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 9):

For me the app [Fine Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=opotech.finevolumev2) was the solution.
It does not need root, unfortunately is not free ($ 2.50) but provides a 7 day trial.

However it does a great job: it subdivides the media volume range in 100 steps, allowing a much finer resolution for your volume choice including enabling to shut the volume to almost nothing. In the setting there is also the option to enable extra low volumes.

Overall it solved the problem for me perfectly and made my phone a much better music player, thus it is worth every penny. To my knowledge this is the only app with this functionality at the moment.

Comment: Tested and does not allow lowering volume below minimum.

Comment: @here, you gave up too soon. In *Preferences -> Advanced preferences* tap on **Volume level**, and you will have 3 options: *Normal, Low, and Extra Low*. The default is Normal, so *try the other two*.

Answer (score 6):

Not a software solution, but you could always try an in-line volume control like this:

[Amazon: Koss VC20 Volume Control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00001P4XH)

You can get one on ebay for close to US $1:

[ebay search: headphone volume control](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=headphone+volume+control)

Comment: will the Koss solution work for in-call volume? that is, can it make the output volume actually be less than the minimum volume provided by the phone?

Comment: Also, what if I don't wan to lose the functionality of the controls on my headphones.

Comment: The answer to both comments is yes. This is a "dumb" physical device that reduces the signal going to the headphones. It doesn't care what mode your phone is in and shouldn't interfere with the functionality of other devices.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a really old thread, but I just bought a bluetooth speaker - a CANZ speaker. It sounds great, capturing all wavelength for pure beats, vocal and instrument separation but it is LOUD - on 1. I went into the standard media player and found the settings and tapped advanced. I was able to lower the whole EQ band by band and found a great volume. Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 3):

On rooted phones, it's possible to install custom kernel which can lower the volume setting lower than is available stock. You might want to look around for custom ROM for your device, if it's a common problem it's highly possible someone would make a custom ROM to modify the volume setting. You'd generally want to try other solutions first though.

Answer (score 3):

the android app, [Maven Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maven.blueplayer&rdid=com.maven.blueplayer), has a "pre volume" control that can lower the sound volume below the minimum setting on your phone.