# minimum in call volume on lg g2 and samsung s4 too high using headphones

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, volume-control, headset, lg, volume

I have tried the Apple and Klipsch earbuds with LG G2 and Samsung S4, however, both phones have a minimum *in-call* volume that is still excessively loud for me. What are some possible solutions? This is not the case when using an iPhone.

I saw [Minimum volume is too high with headphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16313/minimum-volume-is-too-high-with-headphones) suggested getting an inline volume control. Will this only work for music or phone calls as well?

I have tried equalizer apps like Fine Volume Control but these work only for media and not in-call volume, which is my main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this headset : [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00001P4XH/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00001P4XH)

Or Try this application

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=opotech.finevolumev2

Comment: read the question in entirely please